# Auto-Sync CSV file into SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync, csv

Is it possible to auto-sync a CSV File with a SharePoint Online List **without** needing to create an automated PowerShell script (or something similar)?

For example, I have a **People.csv** in my **C:** . Is it possible to link it to a SharePoint List that contains the same Columns, so that whenever I edit the CSV file, the changes reflect onto SharePoint Online as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no built in functionality that does this, if that's what you're asking. You could however write an event receiver that runs whenever the text file is updated in your document library, passes the contents, and then updates the SharePoint list.

You could also use Business Connectivity Services to expose the contents of the text file through a SharePoint list UI, but it isn't precisely a list and has quite a few shortcomings compared to one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want such a script, I created one that should work in your case: https://melcher.it/2017/09/powershell-upload-csv-file-sharepoint-list/

Add it as scheduled task.